# Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in .../civicrm/packages/HTML/Common.php on line 144

Tags: custom-fields, civireport

Has anyone else seen the above error under Joomla and CiviCRM 5.11.0 when running the Event Report: Attendee List?  I've done a bit of troubleshooting and it appears it seems when a custom form value is empty and is then in the form of an empty array rather than an empty string.  A workaround is to test for the variable type and, if it is an empty array, replace it with an empty string.  There seems no longer to be a Joomla demo site, so can't replicate it.[image: $attributes values]

I plan to raise this as an issue, too.

Comment: For demos there is https://joomla.demo.civicrm.org, although it seems an older version.

Comment: I am seeing this error too on Wordpress at this URL: https://mydomain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Freport%2Finstance%2F2

Comment: it's there on drupal as well, using a recent CiViCRM version of 5.21